App Crashes in Android and when run then very slow
When I run my Flutter app on an Android device, the following message appears in the debug console. After that, the app runs, but it is very slow and hangs on my Android device, while it runs perfectly on iOS.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/975288a29268a16cfdce3ed59e808537/transformed/fragment-1.7.1-api.jar!/META-INF/fragment_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/36a29fd5c87a50dba4761ccafb543fa9/transformed/jetified-activity-1.8.1-api.jar!/META-INF/activity_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/bc9b90e24cb2aed3f5a2c3a815096cbd/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3e6ca49c8adc65a57dbf049a365c1b7c/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f908b93b95c727abdd764404408d2ac3/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4e20242732cfa952e26fc62f28c98523/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata-core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1c0eb85853973087f70548d23acccadf/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6c8242a35b839924004f7bf3943601ad/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.13.1-api.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/37785ff6758f9de1990f99562d346a1a/transformed/core-1.13.1-api.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f6bdbb684de0f80f33cf500644e13ab3/transformed/lifecycle-runtime-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b0cf7e8a2ce12047d9e3085e9e36637e/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-process-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-process_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.7.0/85334205d65cca70ed0109c3acbd29e22a2d9cb1/lifecycle-common-2.7.0.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/66b5b2ad32773629fc18c7501b5928cf/transformed/jetified-savedstate-1.2.1-api.jar!/META-INF/savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/cbe8d9cf2abbbd08078e6b40bb00a72d/transformed/jetified-window-1.2.0-api.jar!/META-INF/window_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/419ec37ea4f43936258003227a80bafe/transformed/jetified-window-java-1.2.0-api.jar!/META-INF/window-java_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/90a8787c91fbe2318fe1402b356fbb9b/transformed/jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a4ed5e28ec25a85d910de0787be36f95/transformed/jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-android.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/08c0c3be0d217c354889f680b09d9d84/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/08c0c3be0d217c354889f680b09d9d84/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/08c0c3be0d217c354889f680b09d9d84/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/arleven/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e998f235f4576cf96b2e7b37d69598f5/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

I tried changing the kotlin versions but that did not work
this is my build.gradle
buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = "1.8.0"
   repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
}
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.vezigo"
    compileSdk = 34
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.vezigo"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.22"
    
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'org.jetbrains.kotlin') {
            details.useVersion "1.8.0"
        }
    }
}


flutter {
    source = "../.."
}


It is working fine on iOS but not on Android. Please provide a solution to fix this.

If you've recently updated Android Studio, try deleting the build folder in your Flutter project and then rebuilding the project to ensure a clean start.

You may use Flutter dev tool -> Performance to check fps, ram... to first guess the issue come from your logic code or something else. If it doesn't relate to your logic code, you can clean your simulator, build folder, .pub-cache... and rebuild. Also build release with apk to check whether it's slow or not
